# Is it possible to add an "Executed=*" to ApplicationCommands.*?

Tags: c#, xaml, dockpanel

I wrote some XAML and this is the menu I came up with:

```
<Menu Width="Auto" Height="32" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete Row"  Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" />
    <MenuItem Header="Save Changes" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"/>
</Menu>
```

Now I've noticed the `ApplicationCommands.Delete` does its job nicely, `ApplicationCommands.Save` however does not.
I figured I should make a method that saves these changes, but for some reason I can't add the `Executed=""` property? 
So it could be like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Save Changes" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" Executed="SaveMethod"/>
```

Comment: Well, `MenuItem` has neither a property nor an event `Executed`, so this syntax is not going to work. What is your real problem? What does "does not do its job nicely" exactly mean in your case?

Comment: Maybe you forgot something like `CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your real purpose, this might work:

```
<Menu Width="Auto" Height="32" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <Menu.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"
                        Executed="SaveMethod"
                        CanExecute="CanSaveMethod"/>
    </Menu.CommandBindings>
    <MenuItem Header="Delete Row"  Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" />
    <MenuItem Header="Save Changes" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"/>
</Menu>
```

Or maybe you need to declare a global handler for `ApplicationCommands.Save` through `CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding`.